# TeamCity and compiling kinect project

Tags: c#, teamcity, kinect

I'm working on kinect 2.0 solution and i'm using teamcity for building.

On my machine everything Works fine and i can compile and get .exe file.

On teamcity i get compilation errors, CS1501, CS150*

Does anyone have an idea what could it be?

Comment: Without seeing your code where the error is reported, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the lacky description, first thing that comes to my mind

1. do you have installed kinect sdk on your build agent (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561)? Btw you can also use NuGet packages (http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=kinect) and in this case you don't need sdk on your build agent
2. have you commited all your code?